# Setting up IIS7 on Windows 7

Tags: iis-7

I went through the default install of IIS7 on Windows 7.  I can navigate to http:// localhost and see the default "Hello World" IIS7 content.  But when I browse to http:// machinename from any other machine on my home network (no domain), all I get is 404.  What authentication setting do I need to change?

Answer (score 1):

The 404 could mean that the wrong server or wrong site is catching it since you've already confirmed that the site works with the correct binding.

First make sure that 'machinename' resolves to the right IP for you.  You can confirm by pinging it from the command line.  As long as it does, then the IIS binding needs to listen on that name and IP.  By default Win 7 should use (All Unassigned) or the IP, and a blank host header (and port 80).  That will catch both localhost and machinename.  You can add a 2nd binding if you want that is specifically 'machinename', 80 and blank host header.  That will catch it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the firewall turned on?